# Access denied for rsyslog

Tags: logs, configuration, rsyslog, access-control

Good Morning,

I am trying to sends Zeek logs to another host on my local network with rsyslog.

So far I have a configuration file in /etc/rsyslog.d which looks like this :

```
module(load="imfile")

#### Templates ####
template (name="zeek_Logs" type="string"
          string="<%PRI%>%PROTOCOL-VERSION% %TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %APP-NAME% %PROCID% %MSGID% %STRUCTURED-DATA% %$!msg%\n"
         )

#### RULES for where to send Log Files ####
# Send messages over TCP using the ZEEK_Logs template
ruleset(name="send_zeek_logs") {
    if $msg startswith not "#" then {
        set $!msg = replace($msg, "|", "%7C"); # Handle existing pipe char
        set $!msg = replace($!msg, "\t", "|");

        action (
            type="omfwd"
            protocol="tcp"
            target="192.168.1.140"
            port="7000"
            template="zeek_Logs"
        )
    }
}

#### Inputs ####

input (
    type="imfile"
    File="/opt/zeek/logs/current/weird.log"
    Tag="zeek_weird"
    Facility="local7"
    Severity="info"
    RuleSet="send_zeek_logs"
)

input (
    type="imfile"
    File="/opt/zeek/logs/current/modbus_detailed.log"
    Tag="zeek_detailed"
    Facility="local7"
    Severity="info"
    RuleSet="send_zeek_logs"
)
```

but when launching rsyslog, I get this error :

```
nov. 22 13:00:53 zeek rsyslogd[1442]: imfile: on startup file '/opt/zeek/logs/current/weird.log' does not exist but is configured in static file monitor - this may indicate a misconfiguration. If the file appears at a later time, it will automatically be processed. Reason: Permission denied [v8.2001.0]>
nov. 22 13:00:53 zeek rsyslogd[1442]: imfile: on startup file '/opt/zeek/logs/current/modbus_detailed.log' does not exist but is configured in static file monitor - this may indicate a misconfiguration. If the file appears at a later time, it will automatically be processed. Reason: Permission denied [v8.2001.0]>
nov. 22 13:00:53 zeek rsyslogd[1442]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0" x-pid="1442" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

I tried to give read permission on /opt/zeek/logs directory and I also have disabled apparmor temporarly but nothing works.

What else am I missing ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably user syslog lacks read permission for the directory, you can test it with:

```
sudo -u syslog ls /opt/zeek/logs/current
```

The permission failure may be because of a directory higher up the tree of course. Crude bash example of how to find where:

```
TESTDIR=/opt/zeek/logs/current
while [[ ${#TESTDIR} -gt 1 ]]; do
    sudo -u syslog ls "$TESTDIR" >/dev/null 2>&1 && \
    echo "syslog can read contents of $TESTDIR" || \
    echo "syslog cannot read contents of $TESTDIR"
    TESTDIR=$(dirname "$TESTDIR")
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the syslog user was indeed not allowed to read the /opt/zeek/logs/current directory. I changed it by adding syslog to the user group of zeek and restarted the service but the error remains.

I tried the script you provided and syslog seems to have the rights to read everything.

Comment: Try adding write permission for syslog user for the `current` directory.